# Timesheet groupby weekly

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to find a way to display the weekly timesheets for a particular employee in cakePHP. The Timesheet management is a simple CRUD function which is related to an Activity. I'm looking for a way to group the timesheets created by weeks. For example, if an employee worked 3 days this week, i would like to show the 3 timesheets created for the particular employee for that week in a group and in another div show for the previous week. I have googled and searched stack overflow but haven't come to a solution where it can group the timesheet on weekly bases. It's that or I haven't been googling the right phrases. I apologize in advance if this has been covered but i have been looking for quite a while now.

Thanks,
Will

Comment: Use the the SQL `GROUP BY`.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Start by just getting it working with 3 (or more) separate queries, and then try to make it better from there. If you can post your code with it working using 3 separate queries, it'll be a lot easier for people to help you improve on that code.